# Working with NSTimer

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm creating new game with Swift and SpriteKit.
I'm using NSTimer for create a new objects on scene.
For example:

```
enemyTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector:#selector(GameScene.enemyAppear),userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

But I don't need to use time interval. I want to use distance interval. How can I do this? For example: 50 dots between nodes.
Sorry for my english

Comment: If it's a distance interval, I'm not understanding what this has to do with timers...

Comment: I am assuming he wants something like if a is < 10ft from b, spawn enemy

Comment: By the way, you should avoid using NSTimer in SpriteKit... Search SO about that, there is a lot of talk about this.

Comment: thanks for the your answers guys. NSTimer is not really good thing to create new nodes on scene. And I'm trying to find alternative way to copy some node on my scene. I'm beginner and I know just NSTimer(((

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't need to use time interval. I want to use distance interval.

`NSTimer` doesn't know anything about distances. `NSTimer` does one thing: it sends a message to an object after some time period has elapsed. You supply the message, the object, and the time period. You also have the option to make it repeat or not. That's all it does -- it doesn't monitor object positions or anything like that.

You'll need to keep track of the positions of the objects in question yourself. You could build that functionality into the class you're using for your nodes, or you could create a new class that's patterned after `NSTimer`, but you can't use `NSTimer` for this task.